# VLC - main decoder error: failed to create audio output

Tags: audio, hdmi, vlc

Just installed Raspberry Pi OS Lite 64 bits (no desktop) thanks to "Raspberry Pi Imager"

I did

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I want to play a random mp4 video with VLC.

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && cvlc test.mp4
```

When I define the audio ouput on "bcm2835 Headphones"(via sudo raspi-config), video and audio are OK. Video is playing on screen, and headphone connected to RPI is playing audio.

When I define the audio output on "vc4-hdmi", video is OK, but no audio.

And there are following messages :

```
[721036d0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00b77270] alsa audio output error: no supported sample format
[00b77270] main audio output error: module not functional
[721036d0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00b77270] alsa audio output error: no supported sample format
[00b77270] main audio output error: module not functional
```

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: `update`  ***comes before*** `upgrade`

Comment: Thanks, but issue persist

Comment: i never imagined it would change it, but just sayin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this command

```
 aplay -L
```

Results :

```
    output
hw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Headphones
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Direct sample mixing device
hw:CARD=vc4hdmi,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=vc4hdmi,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=vc4hdmi
    vc4-hdmi, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Default Audio Device
hdmi:CARD=vc4hdmi,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=vc4hdmi,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Direct sample mixing device
```

Modify the vlc command to :

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && cvlc test.mp4 --alsa-audio-device hdmi:CARD=vc4hdmi,DEV=0
```